# Need to Open Two URL while clicking product view page button in grid mode?

Tags: php, jquery, magento

Need to Open Two URL while clicking product view page button in grid mode, Basically its a coupon site. In Grid mode when clicking the product view page button. It has to open product page url & coupon site url. Am facing an error. When clicking the button, It opens the product page of last product in the grid view.

The Code i used is

```js
<p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" 
      onclick="openWindow()"><span><span><?php echo $_product->getCouponCodeUse(); ?></span></span></button></p>           
      <script type="text/javascript">
function openWindow() {
var popup = window.open("<?php echo $_product->getCouponUrlValue() ?>","_self");
            window.open("<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>","window1");
   
}</script>
```

Help me out in this issue

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is  a working fiddle example that opens 2 windows on the same click event.

```
jsfiddle example
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mdamia/mkcvmbhj/9/